# Can I cast two swift spells in a round, or otherwise trade a move action for a swift?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

Can you use a move action to make a swift action?

What if you have 2 swift spells and a standard one, can you cast them all in one round?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**

If you have two swift action abilities you cannot traditionally use both in the same round unless you have some sort of Rule 0 or power from another effect that specifically allows it.  I did look into Standard Action rules to see if you can use a standard action on a swift one (as sort of a downgrade as it were) but the description below clearly debunks that.  So if you have two swifts and a standard, one of those swifts will just have to wait until your next turn.

According to d20PFSRD:

> A swift action consumes a very small amount of time, but represents a larger expenditure of effort than a free action. You can perform one swift action per turn without affecting your ability to perform other actions. In that regard, a swift action is like a free action. **You can, however, perform only one single swift action per turn, regardless of what other actions you take.** You can take a swift action anytime you would normally be allowed to take a free action. Swift actions usually involve spellcasting, activating a feat, or the activation of magic items.
>
> *Cast a Quickened Spell*:
>
> You can cast a quickened spell (see the Quicken Spell metamagic feat), or any spell whose casting time is designated as a free or swift action, as a swift action. **Only one such spell can be cast in any round, and such spells don't count toward your normal limit of one spell per round.** Casting a spell as a swift action doesn't incur an attack of opportunity.

D20 SRD says the same but with about half the paragraph so I gave the longer answer since you tagged both 3.5e and Pathfinder.

Answer (score 7):

## Actions Taking More Time Can't Be Traded for Actions Taking Less Time

The action system in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* and derivative works is strict--*so* strict that breaking it is often the goal of system optimizers. When a character can do more or different things with the typical allotment of actions, the universe sobs.

By default, during a turn, a creature can take 1 standard action, 1 move action, 1 swift action, 1 5-ft. step if no other movement has been used, and any number of free actions the DM permits. A full-round action can be taken instead of both 1 standard action and 1 move action. A second move action can be taken instead of a standard action (*PH* 138). If a creature takes an immediate action, it can't take a swift action on its next turn.

The game explains what a creature can do, not what a creature can't do unless it's clarifying, so despite the initial batch of actions taking increasingly smaller amounts of actual, character-point-of-view time, a creature without special abilities specifically allowing it to do so *can't* exchange a longer action for a shorter action (e.g. a creature *can't* take a second swift action instead of taking a move action) nor combine shorter actions to take longer ones (e.g. a creature *can't* shove together its 5-ft. step, its swift action, and all its free actions to take an additional standard action). That's just not a thing.

**Use Tokens to Track Actions**
If the concept's a struggle, it's often better to think about a creature's turn in terms of tokens and spending tokens to take actions. Make 2 piles of tokens, one for the creature's current turn and another for the creature's *upcoming* turn, with each pile containing the following:

- 1 red token: full-round action. If the creature takes this action, it also spends 1 orange token and 2 yellow tokens.
- 1 orange token: standard action. This also spends the red token and 1 yellow token.
- 2 yellow tokens: move action. Spending 1 yellow token also spends the red token if it remains. If the creature spends the *second* yellow token and it still has the orange token, it spends the orange token, too.
- 1 green token: swift action. If, after its turn ends, the creature takes an immediate action, it spends the *upcoming* turn's green token.
- 1 blue token: 5-ft. step. This is an even trickier one. The creature can *only* spend this token if he has *not* otherwise traversed 1 or more squares, and once he spends this token he *can't* traverse more squares using other actions.
- Infinite indigo tokens: free action. (You might need to visit an arts & crafts store.) If the creature speaks after its turn ends, it spends an *upcoming* turn's indigo token. The DM may let a creature speak anyway, even if the creature has no indigo tokens (like when it hasn't gotten a turn yet) (*PH* 144).

There's more to it than this (as if this isn't complex enough already) and special circumstances abound, but this should permit muddling through.

If you find this particularly useful, I suggest adding violet tokens to each turn's pile representing the creature's number of attacks of opportunity (*PH* 137). Spend 1 violet token from the upcoming turn pile when a creature takes an attack of opportunity.

**An Example**
You round a dungeon corner to find an orc with a battleaxe up in your grill. Initiative is rolled, and you go first. You make 2 piles of tokens--this turn's pile and the upcoming turn's pile--, each containing 1 red, 1 orange, 2 yellow, 1 green, 1 blue, and infinite indigo tokens.

- Your Turn: You take a 5 ft. step to get out of melee range of the orc (1 blue token). You take a standard action to cast the spell *magic missile* [evoc] (*PH* 251) at the orc, who doesn't die (1 orange token and 1 red token). You take a free action to say, "Why didn't I prepare *color spray*?" (1 indigo token). You take a free action to drop your crossbow (1 indigo token). You take a move action to draw your morningstar (the *second* yellow token). Your turn ends.
- The Orc's Turn: The orc takes a 5 ft. step to enter melee range (1 blue token). The orc takes a free action to enter a rage (*PH* 25) (1 indigo token). He says, "Die, finger-wiggler!" (1 indigo token). The orc takes a full-round action to make a full attack (1 red token, 1 orange token, 2 yellow tokens). You take a free action to say, "Magic trumps axes" (1 indigo token from the upcoming turn). You take an immediate action to cast the spell *permeable form* [trans] (*LoM* 129) (1 green token from the upcoming turn). The orc howls in frustration (1 indigo token).

On your turn you'll have 2 piles of tokens--this turn's pile and the upcoming turn's pile--, with this turn's pile containing 1 red, 1 orange, 2 yellow, 1 blue, and infinite indigo tokens, but no green token because you spent that already; and the upcoming turn's pile containing 1 red, 1 orange, 2 yellow, 1 green, 1 blue, and infinite indigo tokens.

---

**Credit Where Credit's Due:** The Use Tokens for Actions idea is from somebody's blog (although these words are mine), but I can't remember whose. I'll link to it if someone finds it.

Comment: In case of colorblind players (I have one so this comes up frequently) you can just use coins per action in a turn - one side is "ready" and one side is "spent".  It wouldn't take much to print a grid with action designated spaces.

Comment: It's a good idea to implement, I've never thought on that. I just have to get (or create) some tokens

Answer (score 2):

No, the only default action-trading available are standard for move, or move+standard for full-round.<sup>1</sup> You cannot trade any other action to get more swift actions. In fact, getting more swift actions is extremely limited:

## The only way in 3.5 to take more than one swift action in a turn is RKV

The ruby knight vindicator from *Tome of Battle* gains the ability to burn a use of Turn-or-Rebuke Undead for an extra swift action in a turn. This is literally the only option in all of 3.5 that allows more than one general-purpose swift action in a round.

---

1. <sup>Some argue that full-round is only available is you trade in all actions (including swift), since that is the wording used in the *Player’s Handbook*, but since that book predates the introduction of swift actions, I consider this to be just an artifact of where things stood at the time.</sup>

Comment: In *Pathfinder* the third-party base class [time thief](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/super-genius-games/time-thief) at level 1 has the special ability mote of time, allowing the character 4/day (but only 1/round) to take a free action to take an extra swift action.

Comment: @HeyICanChan That’s pretty neat; I may have to check that class out.

Answer (score 1):

> What if you have 2 swift spells and a standard one, can you cast them all in one round?

This is definitely a no-no because you're technically adding actions. A Swift action is definitely more valuable than a Move Action. So 2 Swift + 1 Standard would be better.

That stated, as a Pathfinder DM if you wanted to make 2 Swift actions and 0 Standard actions, I would probably allow this. Swift actions are less powerful than Standard actions, so if you took an Immediate Action and then needed to cast a spell on your turn that had a casting time of Swift, I would let you do that instead of your Standard. It might be a minor rules break, but you're not technically trying to cheat, you're trying to do something small instead of something big.

Comment: There is a case where 2 swift actions can be more powerful, such as using Ki points and the activation of some magic items.

Answer (score 0):

**No,** RAW do not allow for any way to take more than one swift action per round, nor to use a standard, move-equivalent, or full-round action to do something that can normally be done as a swift action.

That said, as a DM I've always allowed players to sacrifice their standard action, but not their move action, for a second swift action, but only if they are significantly different types of swift actions - so using a skill trick and casting a swift spell would be ok, but not two swift spells, and probably not for a swift spell after having used Feather Fall as an immediate action.